# Error: unable to verify the first certificate when using SNICallback in node.js express server

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, lets-encrypt, sni

I'm running an express web server with SSL certificate provided by Let's Encrypt as below:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var http = require('http');
    let https = require('https');

    const app = express();

    let privateKey  = fs.readFileSync(SERVER_KEY, 'utf8');
    let certificate = fs.readFileSync(SERVER_CRT, 'utf8');
    let certauth = fs.readFileSync(SERVER_CA, 'utf8');
    let credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate, ca: certauth};

    //HTTPS server
    const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
    httpsServer.listen(443);
    
    //HTTP redirect server
    const httpServer = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        res.writeHead(301, { "Location": "https://" + req.headers['host'] + req.url });
        res.end();
    });
    httpServer.listen(80);
```

The certificate chain parameters are populated as:

`SERVER_KEY=/etc/letsencrypt/live/dummy.example.com/privkey.pem SERVER_CRT=/etc/letsencrypt/live/dummy.example.com/cert.pem SERVER_CA=/etc/letsencrypt/live/dummy.example.com/chain.pem`

Which works well and I can access the web-server both via a browser and via other applications (node.js, java etc)

However, when the certificates expire and are auto-renewed, the web-server must be restarted for this to take effect. To get around this, I have attempted to implement SNICallback with tls secure context so that the certificate chain is read in real time for each request instead of the cached version:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var http = require('http');
    let https = require('https');
    var tls = require('tls');       
    
    const app = express();
    
    function getCredentials(){
        let privateKey  = fs.readFileSync(SERVER_KEY, 'utf8');
        let certificate = fs.readFileSync(SERVER_CRT, 'utf8');
        let certauth = fs.readFileSync(SERVER_CA, 'utf8');
        let credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate, ca: certauth};
        return credentials;
    }
    var ctx = function() { return tls.createSecureContext(getCredentials()) };

    //HTTPS server
    const httpsServer = https.createServer({
        SNICallback: (servername, cb) => cb(null, ctx())
    }, app);
    httpsServer.listen(443);

    //HTTP redirect server
    const httpServer = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        res.writeHead(301, { "Location": "https://" + req.headers['host'] + req.url });
        res.end();
    });
    httpServer.listen(80);
```

This appears to work as intended when accessing the server via a browser (when refreshing the certificate with a new expiry, the new certificate is picked up when the page is refreshed).

However, any attempt to connect via other applications is now hitting the following error:

`Error: unable to verify the first certificate`

suggesting that the intermediate certificate is not being provided by the server in the certificate chain.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tlscreatesecurecontextoptions) the chain (i.e. intermediate certificates) should be provided together with the certificate in `cert`. `ca` is instead used for certificate validation (of client certificates). Based on your description you attempt to provide the chain in `ca` though and not in `cert`.

Comment: Changing the credentials.cert from cert.pem to chain.pem results in `Error: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch` and then nothing works. I still don't understand why using SNICallback with TLS secure context gives a different result to the original configuration

Comment: Ah never mind, double checked and chain.pem only contains the intermediate certificate and above in the chain... fullchain.pem also contains the certificate from cert.pem. Assigning this to credentials.cert fixed the issue - thanks!